# inbuilt web-browser for netbeans like in eclipse

Tags: java, netbeans, browser

Like in eclipse there is an embedded browser , is there a way i can embed a browser in netbeans. Eclipse by default comes with a browser but netbeans doesn't. Is there any plugin that could allow me to add this functionality ?

Comment: I have a dual screen setup and don't like the built in browser at all. I'm very curious of any positive answers though.

Comment: not the dual screen,but a browser screen in a new tab is a good thing in my opinion

Answer (score 1):

There's an [embedded browser](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/38508/embedded-browser) and a [web preview](http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/37621/web-preview) plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the The [DJ Project](http://djproject.sourceforge.net/ns/) for embedding the native browser in netbeans platform. It has a nice How to for netbeans platform in the downloaded archive.

Answer (score 1):

Yes there is one plugin available for netbeans which provides the in built browser along with developer's tool. Here is the link for that:

http://plugins.netbeans.org/plugin/38508/embedded-browser.